# Displaying column names and values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the column names along with the values in the PHP page.

```
while($get_info = mysql_fetch_row($orderdetails))
{
    foreach ($get_info as $field)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $field . "</td>";
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

This fetches just the values. How do I display the column names too?

The column names are `order_id`, `productid`, `product_discount`, `amount`, `customerid`, `order_date`.

Comment: I suggest u to accept an answer if u got ur answer.

Comment: @madhu Remember to "CHECK" one of the answer, its what makes this site alive...

Answer (score 5):

```
while($get_info=mysql_fetch_array($orderdetails))
{
    foreach ($get_info as $key => $val)
        {
            echo "<td>" .$key. ': ' . $val . "</td>";
        }
            echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are just missing the key from your foreach :

```
while($get_info=mysql_fetch_assoc($orderdetails))
{
    foreach ($get_info as $field => $value)
    {
        echo "<td>" .$field.': '.$value."</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

You might want to review your foreach php documentation for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` won't return an associative array.

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks, didn't see the guy used mysql_fetch_row, fixed

Answer (score 3):

If you want each field to contain the column name, change it to `mysql_fetch_array` and do:

```
foreach($get_info as $key => $value) {
    echo "<td>$key: $value</td>";
}
```

If you want the column names to be at the top of the table, you can either check the first row (if you're sure the table won't be empty):

```
$first = true;

while($get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderdetails)) {
    echo '<tr>';

    if($first) {
        $first = false;

        foreach(array_keys($get_info) as $columnName) {
            echo '<th>' . $columnName . '</th>';
        }

        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

    foreach($get_info as $field) {
        echo '<td>' . $field . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

If you're *not* sure that the table will have at least one element, I would use a second `DESCRIBE` query.

Comment: @madhu: Are you sure you read this part? *"change it to `mysql_fetch_array`"*

Comment: yeah...your array_keys will display the column number as well

Comment: sorry not array_keys but it should be mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: @madhu: Oh, you're using the second one. Try `mysql_fetch_assoc` then instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while ($get_info=mysql_fetch_assoc($orderdetails))
    {
        foreach ($get_info as $columnName => $field)
            {
                echo "<td>$columnName: $field</td>";
            }
                echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Notice that I am using mysql_fetch_assoc() which fetches the row having the column names as the keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 while($get_info=mysql_fetch_array($orderdetails))
 {
    foreach ($get_info as $key => $val)
    {
        echo "column is " .$key. 'and value is  ' . $val ;
    }
        echo '</br>';
  }




     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are using a key => val demo but your code will work its just that your $field is now an a key so you need to tell it what column to look at.

When echoing just go

```
echo "<td>" . $field->column . "</td>";
```

That should work.